# How to use templates in strapi

Tags: strapi

I was trying to use the default template in a rest query using this:

```
/company/somecompanyid?template=default
```

But I still get all the data from my mongodb including fields and collections of related tables that are not in the templates.

This is also defined as the defaultTemplate in the model but it doesn't seems to impact the results in any way.

1. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to apply the template?
2. If I want to include just the object Id rather than a whole related object in the reply, how do I specify it in the template?

company.js:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

// Node.js core.
const path = require('path');

// Public node modules.
const _ = require('lodash');
const anchor = require('anchor');

// Local dependencies.
const WLValidationError = require('../../../node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLValidationError');

// Settings for the Company model.
const settings = require('./Company.settings.json');

/**
 * Export the Company model
 */

module.exports = {

  /**
   * Basic settings
   */

  // The identity to use.
  identity: settings.identity,

  // The connection to use.
  connection: settings.connection,

  // Do you want to respect schema?
  schema: settings.schema,

  // Limit for a get request on the list.
  limit: settings.limit,

  // Merge simple attributes from settings with those ones.
  attributes: _.merge(settings.attributes, {

  }),

  // Do you automatically want to have time data?
  autoCreatedAt: settings.autoCreatedAt,
  autoUpdatedAt: settings.autoUpdatedAt,

  /**
   * Lifecycle callbacks on validate
   */

  // Before validating value
  beforeValidate: function (values, next) {
    // WARNING: Don't remove this part of code if you don't know what you are doing
    const api = path.basename(__filename, '.js').toLowerCase();

    if (strapi.api.hasOwnProperty(api) && _.size(strapi.api[api].templates)) {
      const template = strapi.api[api].templates.hasOwnProperty(values.template) ? values.template : strapi.models[api].defaultTemplate;
      const templateAttributes = _.merge(_.pick(strapi.models[api].attributes, 'lang'), strapi.api[api].templates[template].attributes);

      // Handle Waterline double validate
      if (_.size(_.keys(values)) === 1 && !_.includes(_.keys(templateAttributes), _.keys(values)[0])) {
        next();
      } else {
        const errors = {};

        // Set template with correct value
        values.template = template;
        values.lang = _.includes(strapi.config.i18n.locales, values.lang) ? values.lang : strapi.config.i18n.defaultLocale;

        _.forEach(templateAttributes, function (rules, key) {
          if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Check rules
            const test = anchor(values[key]).to(rules);

            if (test) {
              errors[key] = test;
            }
          } else if (rules.required) {
            errors[key] = [{
              rule: 'required',
              message: 'Missing attributes ' + key
            }];
          }
        });

        // Go next step or not
        _.isEmpty(errors) ? next() : next(new WLValidationError({
          invalidAttributes: errors,
          model: api
        }));
      }
    } else if (strapi.api.hasOwnProperty(api) && !_.size(strapi.api[api].templates)) {
      next();
    } else {
      next(new Error('Unknow API or no template detected'));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Lifecycle callbacks on create
   */

  // Before creating a value.
  // beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
  //   next();
  // },

  // After creating a value.
  // afterCreate: function (newlyInsertedRecord, next) {
  //   next();
  // },

  /**
   * Lifecycle callbacks on update
   */

  // Before updating a value.
  // beforeUpdate: function (valuesToUpdate, next) {
  //   next();
  // },

  // After updating a value.
  // afterUpdate: function (updatedRecord, next) {
  //   next();
  // },

  /**
   * Lifecycle callbacks on destroy
   */

  // Before updating a value.
  // beforeDestroy: function (criteria, next) {
  //   next();
  // },

  // After updating a value.
  // afterDestroy: function (destroyedRecords, next) {
  //   next();
  // }
};
```

the template which is a subset of the company attributes (CompanyDefault.template.json):

```
{
  "default": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": {
        "required": true
      },
      "address": {},
      "phone": {},
      "email": {}
    },
    "displayedAttribute": "name"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your default template file? Then, to use the template system, you have to generate your model from the Studio or the CLI. The template logic is located in the "/api/company/models/Company.js" file in your case. It will be interesting to show us this file too.

You're using the right way to apply the template. Your URL seems good! However, this is not possible to include only the object ID rather than the whole related object for now. To do this, I advise you to use GraphQL, or an RAW query...

In the V2, we will support the JSON API specifications in Strapi, this will fit with your problematics for sure!

PS: I'm one of the authors of Strapi.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the questions to include the required files

Comment: That's crazy, your file `Company.js` looks perfect and your template too! Can you log your `template` and `templateAttributes` variables on line 63?